# Is it possible to calculate the space that html content will occupy on a default-zoomed screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML/CSS/JS question:  You have simply-formatted HTML pages with text content.  Imagine, if you will, something like

```
<p>content</p>
<div>content2</div>
<ul>
    <li>c1</li>
    <li>c2</li>
</ul>
```

all of which only contains text, with variable formatting based on css.
You would like to display this content in a certain area on the page.  Assume that for the purposes of this discussion this area is assumed to be sufficiently large enough to display content of any 1 set of tags that are not nested with other tags.

1)you do not want the content to overflow the area of display on the page
2)you don't want to create scrollboxes  in the area of display on the page

Is it possible to dynamically calculate how much of this content you can display on the screen? If so, I would use this information to chunk the content and through JS show the pieces in a powerpoint manner.

Comment: You could try using monospaced fonts, each letter in these fonts use the exact same horizontal width. You could then tell how much space would be used, otherwise every other fonts have different spaces between each letter, this is by design to make it easier to read each word. Typography is a very expansive thing to learn though.

Comment: question is pretty vague on guidelines other than no scroll and no overflow. Yes you can do all sorts of calculations to check dimensions

Comment: But can you do it with a variable-sized area?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$('#something').width()
```

and

```
$('#something').height()
```